# Where is Apache Ignite 2.x source code?

Tags: github, ignite

I checked Ignite on Github, and it seems not to be updated for several months. Where can I find the latest source code?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you check on GitHub? Ignite master branch has new commits every day.

Official repository is `git://git.apache.org/ignite.git`, which is mirrored at https://github.com/apache/ignite.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... According to the Github mirror, the last commit was about 3 hours ago:
https://github.com/apache/ignite

The original Apache repository is here:
https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ignite.git

The 2.0 source code is all in master. There is also a 2.0 tag in GIT.